# filter data based on specific day and time from mongo collection from pool of datadifferent time on same day

Tags: sql, mongodb, pymongo

I have a use case, where I have to filter data based on specific day and any of items prior to that time on that day from mongo collection in pymongo

Ex:

```
 A- 2018-01-29 10:01:00
 B- 2018-01-29 10:11:00
 C- 2018-01-29 10:23:00

 D- 2018-01-28 11:01:00
 E- 2018-01-28 11:04:00
```

I have filter key 2018-01-29 10:24:00, then I have to return only A, B and C. If I have filter Key as 2018-01-28 11:05:00, then I have to return only D and E. If I have criteria 2018-01-29 10:13:00, then I have to return A and B. If I have filter key as 2018-01-28 11:02:00, then I have to return D only. Expanding this, The  other condition is If I have key as 2018-01-28 11:02:00, then CASE A should return D and CASE B should return E. Similarly for Key 2018-01-29 10:13:00, CASE A should return A and B and CASE B should return C only.

Comment: Why not just pass two dates as input ? one on the top of the hour and other date and you can try `db.col.find({date:{$gte:date1, $lte:date2}})`

Answer (score 0):

you need to find all records less than the entered time also it should be on same hour, you could try

`searchDate` is the date condition

`$date` is from the collection

```
db.col.find(
    {$expr : 
        {$and : 
            [
                {$lte: ["$date", searchDate]}, 
                {$eq : [ {$hour : "$date"}, {$hour : searchDate}]},
                {$eq : [ {$dayOfMonth : "$date"}, {$dayOfMonth : searchDate}]},
                {$eq : [ {$month : "$date"}, {$month : searchDate}]},
                {$eq : [ {$year : "$date"}, {$year : searchDate}]},
            ]
        }
    }
)
```

aggregate pipeline

```
db.col.aggregate([
{$match:
    {$expr : 
        {$and : 
            [
                {$lte: ["$date", searchDate]}, 
                {$eq : [ {$hour : "$date"}, {$hour : searchDate}]},
                {$eq : [ {$dayOfMonth : "$date"}, {$dayOfMonth : searchDate}]},
                {$eq : [ {$month : "$date"}, {$month : searchDate}]},
                {$eq : [ {$year : "$date"}, {$year : searchDate}]},
            ]
        }
    }
}
])
```

Comment: It is not about the hour, it is about the same day, less than that specific time (inlcudes hour, min and seconds)

Comment: oh, unfortuantely we dont have trunc to get only date in mongo, we can add date month year as well in `$and` condition

Comment: searchDate can be 2018-01-29 10:13:00 or it should split based on hour , month, day etc., for specific key? as used?

Comment: @TechJump it should be an `ISODate`, are you not storing date as `ISODate`?

Comment: if you have both the dates are `ISODate`s, this will work

Comment: When I have used in pymongo, getting error as indicated below

 coll.find
(
{"$expr" :
{"$and" :
[
{"$lte": ["$date", searchDate]},
{"$eq" : [ {"$hour" : "$date"}, {"$hour" : searchDate}]},
{"$eq" : [ {"$dayOfMonth" : "$date"}, {"$dayOfMonth" : searchDate}]},
{"$eq" : [ {"$month" : "$date"}, {"$month" : searchDate}]},
{"$eq" : [ {"$year" : "$date"}, {"$year" : searchDate}]},
]
}
}
)

with message unknown top level operator $expr

Comment: still have same proble aggregate([
{$match:
    {$expr : 
        {$and : 
            [
                {$lte: ["EDate", ISODate("2017-10-10T09:36:28.287Z")]}, 
                {$eq : [ {$hour :"EDate"}, {$hour : ISODate("2017-10-10T09:36:28.287Z")}]},
                {$eq : [ {$dayOfMonth : "EDate"}, {$dayOfMonth : ISODate("2017-10-10T09:36:28.287Z")}]},
                {$eq : [ {$month : "EDate"}, {$month : ISODate("2017-10-10T09:36:28.287Z")}]},
                {$eq : [ {$year : "EDate"}, {$year : ISODate("2017-10-10T09:36:28.287Z")}]},
            ]
        }
    }
}
])

Comment: `$expr` added in 3.6, if you are on lower version you can clone start date from end date with minutes, seconds and mills set to 0, you can check your date falls in between these start date and actual end date